# Jquery get width of paragraph inside fixed width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to find out the real width of a paragraph inside a container with a fixed width. I added `float:left` to the paragraph thinking this will work but it returns the width of the container width.

**Updated**

CSS

```
.outer {
    max-width: 320px;
    background: #fff;    
    display: inline-block;  
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.inner span {      
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"> 
        <span>
            <p>Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat</p>  
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

I want to alter the width of `.outer` based on the real width of the paragraph but I can't find out the real width. I'm using `$('.inner span').innerWidth())` to output the width.

JSFIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/f2br8ppw/9/

In my example the width of longest line in the paragraph "Vivamus suscipit torto" is visibly smaller than 320px. How can I get the real width of the paragraph? (where the longest line of the paragraph ends is where the width should end - the white background should end at the word "torto")

**The goal:** Perfectly center text that is aligned left. I added a background white in the jsfiddle for a visual guide. Without the background the text doesn't look perfectly centered because there is an obvious space to the right of the paragraph.

Comment: The width you are seeing is the width the element is taking, not the text within it. The text is being wrapped in order to fit the element.

Comment: Provided an updated answer now that the question is clearer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of using JavaScript, I can't think of a way of achieving this. That said, it's rather simple once you do.

We need to set the display of the paragraph to `inline`, which will take it's exact width rather than `inline-block` or using a `float` which will wrap to the container's width once the content spills onto multiple lines.

All we need to do then is to simply calculate the width of the paragraph and the container on load, and space appropriately. [**See Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f2br8ppw/10/):

```js
var $container = $(".outer"),
    $paragraph = $("p", $container);

$container.css("padding-left", ($container.width() - $paragraph.width()) / 2);
```

```css
p {
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: inline;
}

.outer {
    width: 320px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <p>Vivamus suscipit torto eget felis porttitor volutpat</p>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems like this can be achieved with js only.

Answer (score 0):

The output is correct: the width of the paragraph is indeed **320px**. It's not smaller as you think, because width of the `.outer` container is bigger due to padding.

By default actual element width is a sum of the width + padding + border.

You want it to be smaller? Then add [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) rule to `.outer` container:

```
.outer {
    /* ... */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f2br8ppw/4/

Comment: Thank you. It seems that my question wasn't very clear. Please see question update. I clarified at the bottom.